# What is this I hear about the table tag being deprecated?

Tags: html, html-table, deprecated

Because that might mess me up, somewhat.  I'm not entirely clear on what I'm supposed to use to replicate some of its functionality effectively, should I adopt a newer standard down the road.

I can't seem to find good information sources to verify this, though.  Would there be a good reason for this?

Comment: three answers... all with the same answer... go figure.

Comment: If you can't verify something with good sources, then it usually means it's not true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

table tag isn't deprecated (you can look at the html spec). What you've heard of is probably [tableless layouts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design), because tables should not be used for positioning elements on the page.

Comment: The link resolved the key part of what made up my assumption.  Thanks.

Comment: I really think the mindset of "tables should not be used for" is narrow. There are so many different ways of doing the same thing, some less bulky than others, depending on your needs, it really is up to the coder to decide what is best for the situation.

Answer (score 18):

The `<table>` tag is most certainly not deprecated. The thing is, you must (well, *should*) only use it for **tabular data**. It was and sometimes still is being abused for *layout* purposes, which is extremely bad practice for a variety of reasons, and CSS is the preferred technology to use there.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there a function for not using tables to render tabular data, though?  I'm still under the impression there's some kind of drawback to using them (performance?)...

Comment: tables for tabular data is good... just look at the source code for this SO question.

Comment: @rock Actually, SO is demonstrating exactly what you **shouldn't** do. These questions and answers are not in any way tabular data and tables are purely used for layout purposes here, which is Not Good™.

Comment: @Hamster Tables can be bad performance-wise in the sense that a table needs to be downloaded in its entirety before it can be displayed. This is not really an issue for modern browsers, fast internet connections and properly constructed tables though, and it should not be the deciding factor of whether to use a table or not.

Comment: Tables need to be downloaded in full?  Well I guess that's not a huge problem.

What about when I'm rendering my table dynamically?

Comment: @Hamster As I said, moderns browsers are usually intelligent enough to avoid this being a problem, they start rendering tables as soon as possible and re-layout them when necessary. A single table cell usually then becomes the speed limit. Unless you're on a 56k modem though, you usually won't notice a difference anyway. Not quite sure what you mean by "dynamically". Javascript?

Comment: @deceze, since when are comments in a list NOT tabular?

Comment: @rock They're tabular **in layout only**. They're not by themselves **tabular data**. Are you thinking about comments in terms of rows and columns? Do comments have table headers, column descriptions or row names? Would they make sense in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't heard this. I feel I would have with my recent stretch of web conferences.

I will say tables should not be used for layout, strictly tabular data. It's the new semantic web. Maybe that's what you heard.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not being depreciated. I also thought I heard this, however, it was simply a statement implying that the table tag is not as effective as the div tag in terms of layouts as table columns do not drop down when the screen size is reduced.

One thing that I am very concerned about, is that we are yet to have a similar html element that can act as a table, but collapse down like a div in smaller screens without any css. This would really save time as the only thing one would need to declare is the width of each column, and not have to write too much css for column positioning (blocks, inline-block etc).

Comment: It can be done with simple css of float:left; width 100%. (and media queries)