# Issue on Dividing a Div Into Three Columns and Two Rows

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know  how I can divide inside of a div into 3 Columns and 2 Rows like following image?

```
 |--------|--------|---------|
 |        |        |         |
 |   1    |   2    |    3    |
 |        |        |         |
 |---------------------------|
 |        |        |         |
 |    4   |   5    |    6    |
 |        |        |         |
 |--------|--------|---------|
```

I already tried following at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/k5zVe/): but no success!

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="1"></div>
     <div id="2"></div>
     <div id="3"></div>
     <div id="4"></div>
     <div id="5"></div>
     <div id="6"></div>
 </div>

#main{width:300px; height:150px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#1{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#2{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#3{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#4{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#5{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#6{width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Comment: @scrowler Your layout will break when borders are added.

Comment: Sometimes HTML tables are an appropriate element to use.

Comment: @SteveWellens not tables *per se* but rather div's with `table` attributes (tables are deprecated now).

Comment: set width and height in percentage. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/k5zVe/9/).

Comment: @arielnmz - According to this post the table element is **not** being deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176896/html-what-is-this-i-hear-about-the-table-tag-being-deprecated

Comment: @SteveWellens according to that post, it was posted on 2010. It has been 4 years since then. Take a look [at this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), almost all its properties aren't supported on HTML5 and its usage is discouraged.

Comment: @arielnmz `table` element is not deprecated. it is just dicouraged to use from HTML4 onwards.

Comment: @Mr_Green the sense is the same, they should not be used; but I must accept that they work well for testing and learning purposes.

Comment: @arielnmz - Yes, they do work well, not just for testing or learning, but for real applications.  For goodness sakes, there are tables on this very page!  I seriously doubt any browser will stop supporting tables in our lifetime.

Comment: The fact that they're still used doesn't mean they *should* still be used (I have seen sites that still use the `<center>` tag). Ok, I think I should have said *discouraged* instead of *deprecated* (too bad I can't edit my comment) but seriously, what is the problem with accepting `div` as the solution to tables? They're just another markup with better performance and support for CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `div` tags as cells, you may want to take a look at the `table` display attribute:

Example in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3pJp/1/):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="headerCell">A</div>
        <div class="headerCell">B</div>
        <div class="headerCell">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    background: yellow;
}

#header {
    display: table-header-group;
}

.headerCell {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Otherwise, you may want to float your `div` and use the `clear` attribute.

Comment: Doesn't the *you may want* part suggest you something? Hint: It is intended as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="main">
     <div id="1"></div>
     <div id="2"></div>
     <div id="3"></div>
     <div id="4"></div>
     <div id="5"></div>
     <div id="6"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    width: 350px;
    height:200px;
}

#main div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

`#main` should have a width in px greater than 3 times the width of `#main div`
ie `#main_width > 3* div_width`
Height should be specified for the main div and can be defined in percentage for the individual divs.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5zVe/8/

You needed to have each div `float`. I modified the other divs accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main{width:300px; height:150px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#main div{ float:left; width:98px; height:73px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Comment: If you downvote me please have the courtesy of telling me why.

Comment: A bad solution, if the sizes are ever changed or borders are resized, the other number will need to be changed as well. A sustainable solution should require a change only in one place. Also, asking for an explanation on downvotes is silly.

Comment: @Nit - Actually a reason is common courtesy, it's not a bad solution, if you look at what he asked for, it does *exactly* what he asked. He put everything in very specific dimensions.

Comment: In contemporary web development the common fact is that things change, all the time. A good solution doesn't have any gotchas and is easy to maintain. So yes, this is a bad solution.

Comment: Every vote on this site is, inevitably, subjective – whether the voter thinks the post is good or not. Your argument is moot.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things to keep in mind when doing this.

`float: left;` - this aligns each div to stack left next to the last one, and will drop a line when it needs to.

`border: 1px solid #ccc;` - borders are **added** to width and height, so should be taken into account by removing the border width from what you define the div width as.

You don't need to define an ID for each element, use `#main div` instead to cover them all.

[**Updated example:**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5zVe/7/)

```
#main {
    width: 300px;
}

#main div {
    width: 98px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks scrowler but how about height setting?

Answer (score 0):

You may need like this.

HTML :

```
 <div id="main">
    <div id="1" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="2" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="3" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="4" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="5" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="6" class='col'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#main{width:231px; height:154px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
.col { width:75px; border:1px solid #ccc; height:75px; float:left }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ4w3/

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="main">
     <div id="1" class="innerBox"></div>
     <div id="2" class="innerBox"></div>
     <div id="3" class="innerBox"></div>
     <div id="4" class="innerBox"></div>
     <div id="5" class="innerBox"></div>
     <div id="6" class="innerBox"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    width:300px; height:150px; border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.innerBox {
    width:50px; height:75px; border:1px solid #ccc; float:left;
}
.innerBox:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```